# What does "p" stand for in the exponential hex notation for floats

Tags: floating-point, hex, ieee-754, conventions, notation

In hex notation, the number `40.0` is written `0x1.4000000000000p+5` meaning `(1 + 4/16) * 2⁵`.

What does the `p` stand-for?   Presumably, that letter was chosen for a reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It simply means "power"

> By convention, the letter *P* (or *p*, for "power") represents *times two raised to the power of*, whereas *E* (or *e*) serves a similar purpose in decimal as part of the [E notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_notation). The number after the P is *decimal* and represents the *binary* exponent. Increasing the exponent by 1 multiplies by 2, not 16. 10.0p1 = 8.0p2 = 4.0p3 = 2.0p4 = 1.0p5. Usually, the number is normalized so that the leading hexadecimal digit is 1 (unless the value is exactly 0).
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#Hexadecimal_exponential_notation

`P` was chosen because `E` is a valid hexadecimal digits so it may appear in the significand part